# Wordpress Multisite hooked function is bypass

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I hooked a function to the *wp_initialize_site* hook, everything works as expected when I create a new site via **Network Admin** -> **Sites** -> **Add New**. Or if a registered user creates a new site.

The new site should be **archived** and there should be a user meta **_new_site** on the new user, but it doesn't work when creating a new user and site together via **wp-signup.php** with the **Gimme a site!** option. Looks like my function is bypassed.

I also tried to hook the same function to the *wpmu_activate_user* hook and it still doesn't work.

The code more or less like this (I put it in the plugin file):

```
add_action( 'wp_initialize_site', function( $new_site, $args ) {
    update_blog_status( $new_site->id, 'public', 0 );
    update_blog_status( $new_site->id, 'archived', 1 );
    add_user_meta( (int) $args['user_id'], '_new_site', $new_site->id, true );
}, 20, 2 );
```

What I did wrong? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've been able to figure this out but I just stumbled on this and had a similar case that I was able to solve. Your code is close to what you want to achieve and just needs a little tweak.

Checking the [wp_initialize_site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_initialize_site/) hook in the WP documentation, you can access the [Site object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site/) directly and update its properties. This snippet should achieve what you want:

```
add_action( 'wp_initialize_site', function( $new_site, $args ) {
    update_blog_status( $new_site->blog_id, 'public', 0 );
    update_blog_status( $new_site->blog_id, 'archived', 1 );
    add_user_meta( (int) $args['user_id'], '_new_site', $new_site->blog_id, true );
}, 20, 2 );
```

This should work fine to archive your new site and add the id of that site as a user meta.